# Serial Number using nested NG-Repeat

Tags: angularjs

I want to add serial number in each question

```
ng-repeat = "Table in Paper"
   Display table
ng-repeat = "question in question" 
   (1) Display question
   (2) Display question
```

I can use $index in Question. But for each Table, it is started from 1.

E.g.

> Table 1
>
> Question 1
>
> Question 2
>
> Table 2
>
> Question 1
>
> Question 2

But I want

> Table 1
>
> Question 1
>
> Question 2
>
> Table 2
>
> Question 3
>
> Question 4

I use $parent & $index. But not working.

```
<div ng-repeat="section in Table">
 <div ng-repeat="question in section.question">
         <span >{{(Section[$parent.$index-1].question.length + $index + 1 )+
                                    '. ' +
                                    question
                                    .Description}}</span>
     
  </div>
```

Comment: please share your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not the perfect solution what I want, But It can be a temporary solution,

Create watch or function in controller to traverse all question

```
                var index=1;
                Section.forEach(function (section) {
                        section.question.forEach(function (question) {
                            question.Number= index;
                            index++;
                        })
                })
```

Then Print this number in ng-repeat

```
<div ng-repeat="section in Table">
  <div ng-repeat="question in section.question">
     <span >{{question.Number +'. ' +question.Description}}</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ["$scope",function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.lastIndex = 0;
  $scope.lastIndexes = [];
  $scope.Table ={
                  "table1":
                     {
                      "question":["questionA","questionB","questionC","questionD"]
                     },
                    "table2":
                     {
                      "question":["questionA","questionB","questionC","questionD"]
                     },
                    "table3":
                      {
                        "question":["questionC","questionD","questionF"]
                      },
                    "table4":
                      {
                        "question":["questionC","questionD","questionE"]
                      }
                   };
  
  $scope.setLastIndex = function(len){
      $scope.lastIndex = $scope.lastIndex + len*1;
      $scope.lastIndexes.push($scope.lastIndex);
    }

}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   <div ng-repeat="(key,value) in Table"
        ng-init="setLastIndex(value.question.length)">
    {{key}}
 <div ng-repeat="question in value.question" >
         <span>{{($index+1 +lastIndexes[$parent.$index-1])}} :{{question}}</span>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: It gives result table1
1 : question1
2 : qquestion2
table2
1 : question1
2 : qquestion2

But I want 

table1
1 : question1
2 : qquestion2
table2
3 : question1
4 : qquestion2

Comment: Thanks for help. But If Table 1 contains 4 Question then it may not  work

Answer (score 0):

use

```
<div ng-repeat = "Table in Paper">
    <div ng-repeat="q in Table.questions">
        {{q}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Here questions is array and present in your json

Comment: But it will give the number of question in table. But I want global number.

Comment: then use {{q.question}}